# VB.net Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.list to type string

Tags: vb.net, kucoin

Please forgive me in advanced for my lack of coding knowledge.

I'm using a NuGet package called KuCoin.Net and have everything setup and connected. I can run the command and Place a Buy order so I know my Api settings are correct. The issue I'm having is when I run the following code:

```
Public Async Function GetBalancesAsync() As Task
    Dim kucoinClient = New KucoinClient(New KucoinClientOptions() With {
        .ApiCredentials = New KucoinApiCredentials("xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
        .LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug,
        .RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
.FuturesApiOptions = New KucoinRestApiClientOptions With {
    .ApiCredentials = New KucoinApiCredentials("xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
    .AutoTimestamp = False
}})

    Dim accountData = Await kucoinClient.SpotApi.Account.GetAccountsAsync()

    MessageBox.show(accountData.data)
    End Function
```

I guess I'm needing to convert the list to a string so I can display it into a Messagebox.

The Error I recieve is as follows:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Kucoin.Net.Objects.Models.Spot.KucoinAccount]' to type 'System.String'
```

Here is some additional info if this helps

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j1uc.png)

[accountData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSK8A.png)

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Sorry, but the error message is in my opinion pretty clear.  You're trying to treat a collection of Kucoin.Net.Objects.Models.Spot.KucoinAccount as a string.  There really isn't too much more that can be said.  Guessing there might be a string property of the collection elements you might be interested in.  Or you could try MessageBox.show(accountData.data.ToString) although I would suggest little benefit to that.  Do you mean you want to iterate the collection to show some property value?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your String yourself using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) while enumerating through `accountData.Data`:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

For Each account As Kucoin.Net.Objects.Models.Spot.KucoinAccount In accountData.data
    sb.AppendLine(account.ToString)
Next

MessageBox(sb.ToString())
```

You can change `account.ToString` to something more appropriate like `accout.Number` perhaps (see the properties the `KucoinAccount` object has).

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much and yes I had to specify the property of the KucoinAccount Object to get the value I needed. Again THANK YOU

Comment: Glad you are able to move forward from that issue. Please mark the question as answered  when you get a chance.